# Issue with sshd logfile using fail2ban on minimal Ubuntu server 22.04

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, fail2ban, systemctl, journald

I am working on trying to get fail2ban set up and enabled for sshd on my VPS with Ionos. I am using a minimal Ubuntu 22.04 server install.
fail2ban has installed fine, but getting it to run seems a bit complicated.

this is what I keep running into:

> ~$ sudo fail2ban-client -x start
>
> 2023-12-05 19:48:56,976 fail2ban                [4934]: ERROR   Failed during configuration: Have not found any log file for sshd jail

I have looked for /var/log/auth.log but it does not exist. Some quick web searching indicated that because systemd/systemctl/journald take care of logging - but that seems to leave me without a logfile to point to.

here is the relevant portion of my /etc/fail2ban/jail.local:

```
#
# JAILS
#

#
# SSH servers
#

[sshd]

# To use more aggressive sshd modes set filter parameter "mode" in jail.local:
# normal (default), ddos, extra or aggressive (combines all).
# See "tests/files/logs/sshd" or "filter.d/sshd.conf" for usage example and details.
#mode   = normal
#port    = ssh

logpath = %(sshd_log)s
backend = %(sshd_backend)s

enabled  = true
port     = 22443
#--backend  = systemd
maxretry = 3
findime  = 300
bantime  = 3600
ignoreip = 127.0.0.1
```

Can anyone please point me in the right direction?
Thanks :)

Comment: this seems to have solved my issue for the time being but is that really the best answer? ... 

#sudo apt-get install rsyslog

Answer (score 0):

Try to configure to backend systemd, because I think, like Debian 12, they switched to journald logging instead of rsyslog/syslog.
The configuration you posted will never work because the backend is commented out, then fail2ban doesn't know which is logging system is being used and can't read the logs.